# How can I append entries values of an empty dictionary with a for loop in python Tkinter?

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I made entries with a loop. Now, I want to append the values (of the entries) to a dictionary that includes only the Keys. I must do it with a loop because the code would be to long if I append them one by one. I also don't really think that’s how I should reference the values of the entries in line 16.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

superHereos = ['Superman', 'Batman', 'Wonder Woman', 'Green Lantern', 'Flash']
Attributes = ['Name', 'Born', 'From', 'Sex', 'Hair']

Superman = {'Name': [], 'Born': [], 'From': [], 'Sex': [], 'Hair': []}
Batman = {'Name': [], 'Born': [], 'From': [], 'Sex': [], 'Hair': []}
WonderWoman = {'Name': [], 'Born': [], 'From': [], 'Sex': [], 'Hair': []}
GreenLantern = {'Name': [], 'Born': [], 'From': [], 'Sex': [], 'Hair': []}
Flash = {'Name': [], 'Born': [], 'From': [], 'Sex': [], 'Hair': []}

def appendToDict():
    for i in Superman range(len(Superman)):
        Superman['Name'].append(myEntry[0].get())

for entriesRow in range(len(Attributes)):
    myLab = Label(root, text=superHereos[entriesRow])
    myLab.grid(row=0, column=entriesRow+1)
    myLab2 = Label(root, text=Attributes[entriesRow])
    myLab2.grid(row=entriesRow+1, column=0)
    for entriesColumn in range(len(superHereos)):
        myEntry = Entry(root)
        myEntry.grid(row=entriesRow+1, column=entriesColumn+1)

MyButton = Button(root, text='Click me!', command=appendToDict).grid(row=7, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store those superhero names in a list. `root.grid_slaves(row=row, column=column)` will return a list of widgets present at the row/column.

Your `appendToDict` function should look something like this:

```
...
Flash = {'Name': [], 'Born': [], 'From': [], 'Sex': [], 'Hair': []}
superHerosLst = [Superman, Batman, WonderWoman, GreenLantern, Flash]

def appendToDict():
    for heroIndex, hero in enumerate(superHerosLst, start=1):
        for index, att in enumerate(Attributes, start=1):
            widget = root.grid_slaves(row=index, column=heroIndex)[0]
           
            if widget.get() != '':
                hero[att].append(widget.get())
                    
        
    print(superHerosLst)

...
```

`start` argument in `enumerate` is 1 since all your entries start from (1, 1)

It would be better if you append your entries to a list something like this:

```
entriesList = []
...
for entriesColumn in range(len(superHereos)):
        myEntry = Entry(root)
        myEntry.grid(row=entriesRow+1, column=entriesColumn+1)
        entriesList.append(myEntry)
...
```

for `appendToDict` use this:

```
def appendToDict():

    i, j = 0, 0
    for widget in entriesList:
        
        if j == len(superHerosLst):
            j=0
            i += 1
        
        if i == len(Attributes):
            i=0

        att = Attributes[i]
        hero =  superHerosLst[j]
        
        if widget.get() != '':
             hero[att].append(widget.get())

        j+=1                
        
    print(superHerosLst)
```